# Pick up a specific file in the middle of the mule flow

Tags: mule

I have a use case where I need to pick up a specific file from the directory during the middle of the flow.
 I tried using the below code, but It wasnt successful.

Workaround that I am thinking of , is to retrieve all the files , loop and match the file to be picked.

Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: <file:endpoint path="File_Path" connector-ref="File" 
  name="fileEndpoint" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" >
  <file:filename-regex-filter pattern="#[flowVars.fileNameTobePickedUp].txt"  caseSensitive="true"/>
</file:endpoint>

Answer (score 0):

You  could use mule requester to pick up the file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex for responding. I am using Mule Requester to pick up the file.My question is pick up a specific file.

For e.g. 
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt

During runtime in the middle of the flow, say for example I want to pick file2.txt. Using regex-filter-patter, I am getting list of files.Just checking is there a way to pick specific file by setting it in flowVars and pass it to Mule Requester or any other connector.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can read a file in the middle of a flow.
for example, using Groovy scripts:-

```
<set-variable variableName="fileName" value="D:/temp/test2.txt" doc:name="Variable"/>
<scripting:component doc:name="GetFile">                                        
   <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[new File(flowVars.fileName).getText('UTF-8')]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Alternately using Spring beans :-

```
<spring:bean id="myResource" class="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" factory-method="toString">
    <spring:constructor-arg value="file:///D:/temp/file2.txt" type="java.io.InputStream"/>
</spring:bean>
```

and then reading it in a middle of flow:

```
<set-payload value="#[app.registry.myResource]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Third way: You can also use the following to read a file in middle:-

```
<set-variable variableName="fileName" value="file:///D:/temp/file2.txt" doc:name="Variable"/>
  <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
   <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
      muleContext.client.request(flowVars.fileName, eventContext.timeout)
        ]]></scripting:script>
 </scripting:component>
```

The choice is yours :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mule requester to pick the file in the middle of the flow.

Comment: Hi mr Satya, This answer is already given so what is the point of writing same answer again which doesn't make any sense ? pls check the guidelines here before posting an answer. pls give an alternative suggestion that adds value to the question

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this problem by separating the file connector flow into another flow and reference it from the parent flow. When you separate the file connector flow, remember to put the

```
file connector
```

as the inbound endpoint. So whenever your parent flow (which has presumably the HTTP inbound endpoint) receives the request, you can also access it. Further, if you want the file path to be provided by the HTTP endpoint, then you may define a flow variable and store the filepath in it.